# Sandbox paypal php Payment sent to null not verifying

Tags: paypal

I'm having a problem on the sandbox paypal I can't seem to make the payment status go through it always says "Unclaimed" and also I noticed that "Payment sent to null".

here is my code. what I did on the notify_url.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

here is the paypal issues.

[image]

Comment: What its mean `here is my code`? Where is your code?

Comment: sorry @Puneet here is the code for the paypal not sure if why its unclaimed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `first_name` and `last_name` to fix the null problem.

Here's some info about [unclaimed payments](https://www.paypal.com/fm/smarthelp/article/what-does-a-status-of-unclaimed-mean-faq2038).  Maybe the sandbox account you're working with does not have a Confirmed address..??